# Amplify Error: auth headless init is missing the following inputParams facebookAppIdUserPool, facebookAppSecretUserPool

Tags: authentication, aws-amplify

G'day,

I had a working Amplify project. Well, it was all good until I run `amplify add auth` and push the changes to master. I was following the instruction here https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh

Now I got the following error and my master is red :(

Can't find anything useful in the amplify documentation. I did try to run the `headless_init_env_auth.sh` script from this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/tree/master/packages/amplify-cli/sample-headless-scripts but it doesn't help.

This error doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

````
2019-06-18T11:16:53.459Z [INFO]: Error: auth headless init is missing the following inputParams facebookAppIdUserPool, facebookAppSecretUserPool, googleAppIdUserPool, googleAppSecretUserPool
                                 at updateConfigOnEnvInit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/provider-utils/awscloudformation/index.js:287:15)
                                 at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-category-auth/index.js:201:28
                                 at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/promise-sequential/index.js:16:18
                                 at <anonymous>
                                 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
2019-06-18T11:16:53.466Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2019-06-18T11:16:53.466Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected```
````

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define **facebookAppIdUserPool, facebookAppSecretUserPool, googleAppIdUserPool, googleAppSecretUserPool** in AUTHCONFIG.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'

AUTHCONFIG="{\
\"facebookAppId\":\"fbid1\",\
\"googleClientId\":\"goog\",\
\"facebookAppIdUserPool\":\"facebookAppId\",\
\"facebookAppSecretUserPool\":\"facebookAppSecret\",\
\"googleAppIdUserPool\":\"facebookAppSecret\",\
\"googleAppSecretUserPool\":\"googleAppSecret\"\
}"
AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"project\",\
\"useProfile\":true,\
\"profileName\":\"default\"\
}"

AMPLIFY="{\
\"envName\":\"dev8\"\
}"
PROVIDERS="{\
\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG\
}"
CATEGORIES="{\
\"auth\":$AUTHCONFIG\
}"

amplify init \
--amplify $AMPLIFY \
--providers $PROVIDERS \
--categories $CATEGORIES \
--yes
```

or can use Amplify-CLI command

```
amplify init \
--amplify "{\"envName\":\"dev\"}" \
--categories "{\"auth\":{\"googleAppIdUserPool\":\"googleAppId\",\"googleAppSecretUserPool\":\"googleAppSecret\"}}" \
--yes
```

Comment: While undocumented, this is theoretically sound and a fine answer. However, I could not get `amplify init --categories` to work. Others have the same problem: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1979

Answer (score 10):

A simple fix for me is to update the environmental variable from amplify.

AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_ID

AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET

AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID

AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET

AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID

AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

Comment: Fixed this with setting these env variables in the console to bogus values and rebuilding succeeded

Comment: this method worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The workaround on my end was the following:

1. Create environment variable for the Auth Resource by `App settings` > `Environment variables` and add these environment variables values: `AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID`, `AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET`, `AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, `AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET`, `AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_ID` and `AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET`
2. Create your own `amplifypush.sh` in root folder `amplify-auth-app/myamplifypush.sh` (amplify-auth-app beind your project made for instance in React)
3. Add your auth configs to the bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
IFS='|'

help_output () {
    echo "usage: amplify-push <--environment|-e <name>> <--simple|-s>"
    echo "  --environment  The name of the Amplify environment to use"
    echo "  --simple  Optional simple flag auto-includes stack info from env cache"
    exit 1
}

init_env () {
    ENV=$1
    AMPLIFY=$2
    PROVIDERS=$3
    CODEGEN=$4
    AWSCONFIG=$5
    CATEGORIES=$6

    echo "# Start initializing Amplify environment: ${ENV}"
    if [[ -z ${STACKINFO} ]];
    then
        echo "# Initializing new Amplify environment: ${ENV} (amplify init)"
        [[ -z ${CATEGORIES} ]] && amplify init --amplify ${AMPLIFY} --providers ${PROVIDERS} --codegen ${CODEGEN} --yes --minify || amplify init --amplify ${AMPLIFY} --providers ${PROVIDERS} --codegen ${CODEGEN} --categories ${CATEGORIES} --yes --minify
        echo "# Environment ${ENV} details:"
        amplify env get --name ${ENV}
    else
        echo "STACKINFO="${STACKINFO}
        echo "# Importing Amplify environment: ${ENV} (amplify env import)"
        amplify env import --name ${ENV} --config "${STACKINFO}" --awsInfo ${AWSCONFIG} --yes;
        echo "# Initializing existing Amplify environment: ${ENV} (amplify init)"
        [[ -z ${CATEGORIES} ]] && amplify init --amplify ${AMPLIFY} --providers ${PROVIDERS} --codegen ${CODEGEN} --yes --minify || amplify init --amplify ${AMPLIFY} --providers ${PROVIDERS} --codegen ${CODEGEN} --categories ${CATEGORIES} --yes --minify
        echo "# Environment ${ENV} details:"
        amplify env get --name ${ENV}
    fi
    echo "# Done initializing Amplify environment: ${ENV}"
}

ENV=""
IS_SIMPLE=false
POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
    do
    key="$1"
    case ${key} in
        -e|--environment)
        ENV=$2
        shift
        ;;
        -r|--region)
        REGION=$2
        shift
        ;;
        -s|--simple)
        IS_SIMPLE=true
        shift
        ;;
        *)
        POSITIONAL+=("$1")
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done
set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}"

# if no provided environment name, use default env variable, then user override
if [[ ${ENV} = "" ]];
then
    ENV=${AWS_BRANCH}
fi

if [[ ${USER_BRANCH} != "" ]];
then
    ENV=${USER_BRANCH}
fi

# strip slashes, limit to 10 chars
ENV=$(echo ${ENV} | sed 's;\\;;g' | sed 's;\/;;g' | cut -c -10)

# Check valid environment name
if [[ -z ${ENV} || "${ENV}" =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9\-]+ ]] ; then help_output ; fi

AWSCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"project\",\
\"useProfile\":true,\
\"profileName\":\"default\",\
\"AmplifyAppId\":\"${AWS_APP_ID}\"\
}"
AMPLIFY="{\
\"envName\":\"${ENV}\",\
\"appId\":\"${AWS_APP_ID}\"\
}"
PROVIDERS="{\
\"awscloudformation\":${AWSCONFIG}\
}"
CODEGEN="{\
\"generateCode\":false,\
\"generateDocs\":false\
}"
CATEGORIES=""
if [[ -z ${AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID} && -z ${AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID} && -z ${AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_ID} ]]; then
    CATEGORIES=""
else
    AUTHCONFIG="{\
    \"facebookAppIdUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}\",\
    \"facebookAppSecretUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET}\",\
    \"googleAppIdUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}\",\
    \"googleAppSecretUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}\",\
    \"amazonAppIdUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_ID}\",\
    \"amazonAppSecretUserPool\":\"${AMPLIFY_AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET}\"\
    }"
    CATEGORIES="{\
    \"auth\":$AUTHCONFIG\
    }"
fi
# Handle old or new config file based on simple flag
if [[ ${IS_SIMPLE} ]];
then
    echo "# Getting Amplify CLI Cloud-Formation stack info from environment cache"
    export STACKINFO="$(envCache --get stackInfo)"
    init_env ${ENV} ${AMPLIFY} ${PROVIDERS} ${CODEGEN} ${AWSCONFIG} ${CATEGORIES}
    echo "# Store Amplify CLI Cloud-Formation stack info in environment cache"
    STACKINFO="$(amplify env get --json --name ${ENV})"
    envCache --set stackInfo ${STACKINFO}
    echo "STACKINFO="${STACKINFO}
else
    # old config file, above steps performed outside of this script
    init_env ${ENV} ${AMPLIFY} ${PROVIDERS} ${CODEGEN} ${AWSCONFIG} ${CATEGORIES}
fi
```

4. Edit Build setting in amplify console to look a bit like this:

```
version: 0.1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - chmod u+x ./myamplifypush.sh
        - ./myamplifypush.sh
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

5. And redeploy

Comment: Thank you so much! After so many hours trying to find a solution, this did it for me.